# Memory not freed after running Clear when using a Table

Tags: memory

When I'm creating large lists with `Table` I see the memory footprint increasing.

```
MemoryInUse[]/1024.
(* Out-> 16992.4 *)

data = Table[x, {x, 0, 10000}, {y, 10000}];    
MemoryInUse[]/1024.
(* Out-> 408372. *)
```

I would expect that when I generate the same command `data = Table[...]` just as above the memory would not increase but in fact it just allocates a new block of memory.

```
data = Table[x, {x, 0, 10000}, {y, 10000}];   
MemoryInUse[]/1024.
(* Out -> 799041. *)
```

Why is that? Even when I do:

```
Clear[data];
MemoryInUse[]/1024.
(* Out-> 799044. *)
```

Is this expected behaviour or am I missing something? I can't seem to find a function that clears the memory.

I'm using Mathematica 8.0.4.0 on Windows 7

Comment: See [common pitfalls / $HistoryLength](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80978/4999)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried setting [`$HistoryLength`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24HistoryLength.html) to zero:

```
$HistoryLength=0;
```

The memory is not freed, because the previous data is still available by `Out[nn]` or `%nn`.

Note that if you do this, using `%`, `%%`, `%n` etc., which some people use in example code will not work. And when a large data set is shown the "Show More" and "Show Less" buttons do not work. You can bypass both problems by setting `$HistoryLength` to 1 while still conserving a lot of memory.