# Why does ImageData need four times more memory?

Tags: import, memory, packed-arrays, image

**Background**

We are dealing with very large TIFF image files that are imported, processed and exported using *Mathematica* 9.0.1. Many of our algorithms only work with an array representation of the images, where pixel values are stored in the form of nested lists. For this, we are currently using the function `ImageData` to directly convert images into an array representation.

**Problem**

I am struggeling with the increase in memory usage when converting images to the array representation using `ImageData`. What I am wondering about is that when I convert images with `ImageData` the allocated memory is four times higher compared to having only the images in memory.

**Example**

Consider the following example: I first create a stack of 50 images that is exported to a TIFF file. Then I import the file again with the option `"Data"`. I check the memory before and after `Import`. Compared to importing the file without any option, this takes up four times more memory.

```
Export["testFile.tif", ConstantArray[Image[ConstantArray[0, {1024, 1024}], "Bit16"], 50]];
FileByteCount["testFile.tif"]
```

> 104901507

```
MemoryInUse[]
```

> 8617736552

```
imgData = Import["testFile.tif", "Data"];
MemoryInUse[]
```

> 9037228760

```
9037228760 - 8617736552
```

> 419492208

If I import the file without the option, the memory used is about 104905128 bytes. This gives a factor of about 4 (3.99) more memory needed. I repeated this several times and I have to admit I do not have any explanation.

**Questions**

1. Is there a simple explanation for the increase of memory usage?
2. How can I reduce the amount of allocated memory when using the array
   representation?

**Attempts**

After reading about the function `Developer`ToPackedArray` in [What is a Mathematica packed array?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array) I tried to convert the data array hoping that this would give me a decrease in memory usage. Nevertheless, I am not really sure if I am using the function correctly in this case. The code I tried is the following:

```
packed = Developer`ToPackedArray[Import["testFile.tif", "Data"]];
```

**System specifictation**

- OS: Windows 7 Professional, Service Pack 1 (64-bit)
- Processor: Intel    Xeon CPU E5630 @ 2.53 GHz (2 Processors)
- Installed memory: 96 GB
- *Mathematica* 9.0.1
- Java version 1.7.0_07

**Additional question**

Still one problem remains: Is their a clean way in *Mathematica*, how I could reduce the number of bits used for Integer to change the amount of memory used for the array representation (`ImageData`) without losing information? Or do I have to stick to `Image` in that case?

Comment: On which operating system are you?

Comment: @Alexander Schmitz perhaps you could check the history settings? [Link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4322/memory-not-freed-after-running-clear-when-using-a-table)

Comment: @halirutan: I added some information about my system.

Comment: @Lou: Thanks for the link. I already read this post. However, the problem is not that memory is not freed. It's not about the history of the current session. My problem is that I do not understand why an array-representation of images needs four times more memory.

Comment: It would be useful if you test this behavior on smaller size files and provide a link to some such file (of a size say 10-20Mb) in the question, to give us something to play with.

Comment: I presume you've already ruled out using `ImageFileApply` and `ImageFileFilter`, which are "used to read, process, and write successive blocks of data from a very large image file whose size could exceed available memory", according to WRI.

Comment: @cormullion: Thanks for your ideas. I have read about these two functions, yes. Usually, my files should fit into the memory without any problem. The thing I am curious about is why the array-representation needs four times more memory.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Good idea, thanks. I wanted to post an example where the difference in memory of both import types can be seen easily (104905128 Bytes vs. 419492208 Bytes). If needed, the dataset can be reduced to 10 images if you use: ConstantArray[Image[ConstantArray[0, {1024, 1024}], "Bit16"], 10]];

Comment: I think it's just that a 16-bit TIFF uses two bytes per pixel, whereas a *Mathematica* `Integer` uses a minimum of 8 on a 64-bit system.

Comment: Packing doesn't help because the data is only unpacked at the first level, i.e. ``Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ imgData`` gives `{True, True, True ...}`

Comment: @SimonWoods: Nice ideas, thanks. I tried to store different types of images. The memory increase seems to be independent from the type. It must have something to do with Mathematica's representation and memory allocation for lists. Am I missing something completely?!

Comment: My assertion that *Mathematica* uses 8 byte (64 bit) integers was wrong. At least on my PC, packed arrays of integers are 32 bit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On my system (Windows 7 64-bit, 12GB, *Mathematica* v8) I only see a factor of 2 between the image file size and the memory used by the image data. This agrees with the observation that packed arrays of integers use 32 bits per element.

To confirm this, a `ConstantArray` containing values of $2^{31}-1$ (the maximum signed 32-bit integer) is packed and has a `ByteCount` corresponding to 32 bits per element, whereas increasing the value by 1 (to a 33 bit number) prevents packing and the array now takes 512 bits per element to store.

```
bitinfo = Module[{arr = ConstantArray[#, {1000}]},
    {If[Developer`PackedArrayQ[arr], "Packed", "Not packed"],
     ToString[Floor[ByteCount[arr], 1000]/125] <> " bits"}] &;

bitinfo[2^31 - 1]
(*  {Packed, 32 bits}  *)

bitinfo[2^31]
(*  {Not packed, 512 bits}  *)
```

Note that small integers still use a 32 bit representation, even though they **could** be stored using fewer bits.

```
bitinfo[1]
(*  {Packed, 32 bits}  *)
```

To understand what is happening with images and tiff files, I wrote this:

```
With[{f = "testFile.tif", data = ConstantArray[0, {1000, 1000}], 
  types = {"Bit", "Byte", "Bit16", "Real32", "Real"}}, 
 Column[{"Bits per pixel for different image types:\n", 
   TableForm[
    Table[Round[
        8 {ByteCount@#, Export[f, #]; FileByteCount@f, 
           ByteCount@Import[f], ByteCount@Import[f, "Data"]}/10^6] &@
      Image[data, type], {type, types}], 
    TableHeadings -> {types, {"Initial\nImage", "Exported\nfile", 
       "Imported\nImage", "Imported\ndata"}}]}]]
```

[image]

The data shows that the image created by `Image[data, type]` uses a bit depth corresponding to the specified `type` (with the exception of `"Bit"` images which use 8 bits per pixel). The exported tiff file uses either 8 bits or 16 bits per pixel (I think these are the only bit depths supported by `Export` for tiff files). The imported `Image` object has the same bit depth as the file, and as expected the packed array of image data uses a bit depth of 32.

The interesting thing is that *Mathematica* can use 8-bit or 16-bit integers for `Image` objects, but packed arrays of integers are always 32-bit. So it's normal that the same data requires more memory as an array than as an `Image`.

The mystery is why you are getting a factor of 4 between a 16-bit image and the corresponding array. Perhaps the bit depth of packed arrays has increased to 64 bits in version 9? Please consider running the code in this answer and reporting what you find.

Comment: In V9, packed arrays uses 64-bit integers on a 64-bit operating system. SystemFiles/IncludeFiles/C/WolframLibrary.h gives the mint type definition and you can check the different definitions for 32- and 64-bit systems. Within Mathematica, Developer`$MaxMachineInteger will give the maximum signed machine integer, which is used in many places within Mathematica including the size of a packed integer array element.  Image does use a different representation.

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation. This really helped me a lot :)

Comment: Judging by your results I suspect the "different representation" mentioned by @JoelKlein is ``System`RawArray`` (relevant functions also in the ``Internal` `` and ``Developer` `` contexts). This supports types `"Byte"`, `"Bit16"`, `"Integer32"`, `"Real32"`, and `"Real"`. It seems that one cannot really manipulate these objects inside *Mathematica*, so its likely reason for being is interoperability.

Answer (score 2):

I also wanted to add the output of the code provided by Simon Woods. I executed it on my  system (Windows 7 (64-bit), 96GB, *Mathematica* v9) as described in the question edit.

When i run the bitinfo function this gives me:

```
bitinfo[2^31 - 1]
(*  {Packed, 64 bits}  *)

bitinfo[2^31]
(*  {Not packed, 64 bits}  *)

bitinfo[1]
(*  {Packed, 64 bits}  *)
```

The `With` produces the following output:

[image: output of With module]

Regarding the output and the comment of Joel Klein, now everything seems to make sense. As Simon said, "*Mathematica* can use 8-bit or 16-bit integers for Image objects, but packed arrays of integers are always 32-bit." Considering that I am using *Mathematica* v9, the memory use is different, because as Joel said, "packed arrays use 64-bit integers on a 64-bit operating system".