# Building a classifier for images

Tags: machine-learning

I tried to build a classifier for some images that I have with the following code:

```
class1 = Import /@ 
   FileNames["*", 
    "location1"];

class2 = Import /@ 
   FileNames["*", 
    "location2"];

classifier = 
  Classify[Join[# -> "H" & /@ 
     class1, # -> "C" & /@ 
     class2]];
```

I believe that this would work, but it crashes with an out of memory error after the system tries to use more than 64GB of RAM.

Total size of all the images in collection is 42MB.

How can I build a classifier that in such a way that it doesn't require more than 64GB of RAM?

**Update:** I converted all the files to `.jpg`, and the issue remained.

Comment: What is the file format of the images?

Comment: @C.E. .tiff. Does it matter?

Comment: Not always, but it can. There is a discussion specifically on .tiff images and memory consumption [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17551/731).

Comment: @C.E. h'm. Should what format should I convert them to as a test?

Comment: I don't know, let's wait and see what others have to say.

Comment: What are you trying to classify? What is special about the two classes of images? How separable are the two classes of images? This is a problem with functions like `Classify` — they promise the world in a black box that can be used unsupervised w/o knowing anything, but it works only when you have infinite memory for it to overfit to every possible combinations of inputs /rant

Comment: I have two types of images (happen to be two types of documents). A human can easily do it, no idea about a machine. Accuracy does not need to be great, but im aiming for a low false negative rate. All images are in in two classes (really its in the class I care about or its not). Does this help?

Comment: I'd begin by turning each image into a feature vector.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: There's no simple answer to that question. You begin by guessing "what values are relevant in these images for an algorithm that would need to distinguish between them?" and then you'd extract values for each of those. So for example, you might extract the brightness of each image. Or maybe how green the image is. You then have a vector of each of these features and use these vectors instead of the image.

Comment: In machine learning, getting the feature vector right is often the real battle.

Comment: Can you try picking a Method manually? Doesn't really matter which one. I get this kind of error too mainly when it is trying to figure out the best method automatically.

Comment: Alternately, you can use ImageResize and use 150x150 or a bit more... you don' need the full size images.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a complete answer (indeed, that would be impossible since we don't have access to the images), but is too long for a comment.

You might try `ImageIdentify[image,category,n]` to generate "feature vectors" consisting of n words. If you are lucky, the best n matches might contain enough information to distinguish the two kinds of images. The advantage of this approach is that you would leverage all the sophisticated image processing inherent in `ImageIdentify` and the classifier needs to only function on the words. So in outline, for each image you would get a list like

```
feat = ImageIdentify[image, All, 5]
```

which returns a 5-vector of where `feat[[All, 2]]` contains the best-match words. These sets of words could then be used in the `Classify` step.